# How to show legend for ggsignif layer in final ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new to ggplot. Here I just wanted to do a simple box plot of level of OPG (a molecule) between three groups, namely "RA", "Control" and "OA". The grouping information is contained in the column "Group". On top of that, I added a ggsignif layer where I used annotation instead of exact p-value. I set "show.legend" to be TRUE but the significance legend is not showing up together with the grouping legend. I am not sure which exact command to use to display the legend for ggsignif layer. I have attached my code and plot below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

set.seed(5)
control <- data.frame(Group='Control',OPG = rnorm(30,mean=45,sd=10))
OA <- data.frame(Group='OA',OPG = rnorm(30,mean=52,sd=12))
RA <- data.frame(Group='RA',OPG = rnorm(30,mean=62,sd=15))
sampledf <- rbind(control,OA,RA)

ggplot(sampledf,aes(Group,OPG))+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.5) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("RA","Control"),
                                 c("OA","RA"),
                                 c('OA','Control')),
              step_increase = 0.1,
              map_signif_level=TRUE,
              show.legend = TRUE) +
  labs(y="Serum OPG Level") +
  theme_light()

``
[![Output][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6OFw.png
```

Comment: Can you add sample data? Also call the packages we need to run your code. Thx

Comment: As far as I know ggplot, it creates legends only for variable that are used in the ```aes(...)```-calls. ```geom_signif``` seems to create only an annotation layer.

Comment: @markus Hi please see edits, I have updated post with packages to call and a sample dataset.